# What do we infer from the shares bid - position in market?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges

I am trying to understand what can I conclude or infer from my position in the market when I have applied for the bid. In terms of number of buyers and the volume. Next in terms of number of sellers and the volume. Also, what is that position number in the bid? Is my bid gets placed in the queue? How does it all work? What this picture shows in terms of supply and demand? Can I infer anything more out of it?

Order Position in the Share market - ASX - Australia Stock Market:

[image: Order Position in the Share market - ASX - Australia Stock Market]

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot that you can infer from a partial snapshot of the order book.  It appears that the market is .375 x .385 and that there are 22 orders that were placed ahead of you.  How much volume is ahead of you is unknown since you only displayed lines 18 to 27 of the sell side.

Orders go on the order book based on price and time, sort of first come, first served.